# After updating to ionic 5 and Angular 9 , error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types

Tags: ionic-framework

After updating to Ionic 5 and Angular 9, I get the following error:

> error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.
>
> ERROR in src/app/providers/firestore-db.service.ts:19:13 - error
> TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types. [ng] 19
> ...doc.payload.doc.data()

This is the related code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FirestoreDbService {
    
      constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }
    
      getAllData(collectionId) {
        /* return this.db.collection('product').valueChanges(); */
        return this.db.collection(collectionId).snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(docArray => {
            return docArray.map(doc => {
              return {
                id: doc.payload.doc.id,
                ...doc.payload.doc.data()
              }
            })
          })
        )
      }
    
      async insertData(collectionId, data) {
        try {
          const result = await this.db.collection(collectionId).add(data);
          return result;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      }
    
      async getDataById(collectionId, docId) {
        try {
          const result = await this.db.collection(collectionId).doc(docId).ref.get();
          if (result.exists) {
            return result.data();
          } else {
            throw new Error('Data not found with given id');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      }
    
      async updateData(collectionId, docId, updatedData) {
        try {
          const result = await this.db.doc(`${collectionId}/${docId}`).update(updatedData);
          return result;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      }
    
      async deleteData(collectionId, docId) {
        try {
          const result = await this.db.doc(`${collectionId}/${docId}`).delete();
          return result;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by downgrading typescript from 3.7.5 to 3.6.4

```
npm install typescript@3.6.4
```

and make sure it is also 3.6.4 in the package.json

Comment: Thanks, I know it's not ideal but I guess Microsoft is dropping the ball on that one :S